# Assign bash variable to X or Y

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

How to assign a bash variable to pathX (if exists) or pathY(if exists) for example:

`export EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano || /bin/nano`

Comment: Why don't you just use `EDITOR=nano` and set your path correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export EDITOR=$(whereis -b nano | awk '{ print $2 }')
```

Run the whereis command to locate the binary for nano and then use the result (parsed through awk) to set the EDITOR variable.

Comment: Unfortunately, I keep my `nano` in the `/home/pax diablo/extra files` directory :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `if`. If you want to check if the file is executable, use `-x`

```
if [ -x /usr/bin/nano ]; then
   export EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano
else
   export EDITOR=/bin/nano
fi
```

Or if you want to be able to use it regardless of the type, use `-e`

```
if [ -e /usr/bin/nano ]
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple conditional inside a loop will do:

```
export EDITOR=
for choice in "/usr/bin/nano" "/bin/nano" ; do
    [[ -x "${choice}" ]] && export EDITOR="${choice}" && break
done
echo "Editor selected is '${EDITOR}'" # debug to see what was chosen
```

This will select the first in the list that exists and is executable, and does not depend on `nano` actually being in your path (although, to be honest, it probably *should* be).